# Proof that function is injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When $f: P(C) \to P(C) \times P(C)$ so that $f(X) = (X\cup A, X\cup B)$ for every $X, C= A\cup B$ and $C$ isn't empty. ($P$ - powerset)

I need to prove that $f$ is injective only when $A\cap B$ is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) $f$ injective $\Longrightarrow A\cap B=\varnothing$:

By contrapositive: if $A\cap B \neq \varnothing$, take $X_1\subset A\cap B$ and note that
$f(X_1)=(A,B)=f(\varnothing)$, so $f$ isn't injective.

(2) $A\cap B=\varnothing \Longrightarrow f$ injective:

Let $X,Y\in P(C)$ such that $f(X)=f(Y)$. Then

$$(X\cup A,X\cup B)=(Y\cup A,Y\cup B)$$ then
$$X\cup A=Y\cup A, X\cup B=Y\cup B$$ then
$$(X\cup A)\cap B=(Y\cup A)\cap B, (X\cup B)\cap A=(Y\cup B)\cap A$$ then
$$(X\cap B)\cup(A\cap B)=(Y\cap B)\cup(A\cap B)$$ then
$$X\cap B=Y\cap B, X\cap A=Y\cap A$$ then
$$(X\cap B)\cup(X\cap A)=(Y\cap B)\cup(Y\cap A)$$ then
$$X\cap(A\cup B)=Y\cap(A\cup B)$$ and so
$$X\cap C = Y\cap C$$
which implies $X=Y$. Therefore, $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is $f(\emptyset)$? What is $f(A\cap B)$?

> $f(\emptyset)=(A,B)$; $f(A\cap B)=f((A\cap B)\cup A,(A\cap B)\cup B)=(A,B)$. So, if $f$ is injective, then $A\cap B=\emptyset$

Suppose now $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Then, for any $X$,

> $X=X\cup\emptyset=X\cup (A\cap B)=(X\cup A)\cap (X\cup B)$. Therefore $X\cup A=Y\cup A$ and $X\cup B=Y\cup B$ implies $X=Y$.

Comment: I loved the "spoilers" ! Such a nice way to give hints in the mse. Can I use that in my answer? XD